# Query to get last 3 month's data in SSIS SQL Command

Tags: ssis, db2, ibm-midrange, db2-400

Hi I am developing an SSIS package in VS2008 for SQL Server 2008.

To read the data from source, I have added the ADO.NET source editor and written below queries in the SQL command window but getting error.

```
Select * 
From Table 
Where CreatedDate Between DATEADD('d', -90, Date()) And Date()
```

Error for above SQL query:

> ERROR [42000] [IBM i [System i Access ODBC Driver] [DB2 for i5 / OS] SQL0170 - Number of arguments for function DATE invalid. (CWBODBC.DLL)

```
Select * 
From Table 
Where CreatedDate Between DateAdd('d', -90, GETDATE()) And GETDATE()
```

Error for this second SQL query:

> ERROR [42S02] [IBM] [System i Access ODBC Driver] [DB2 for i5 / OS] SQL0204 - GETDATE of type * N in * LIBL not found. (CWBODBC.DLL)

Is there anyone who can help me to write the SQL command query to get the last 3 month's data?

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: Could you be a bit more explicit about last three months , is it last 90 days? or last three months excluding the current month? or something else??

Comment: It should be last 3 month's data including current month

Comment: So you're pulling from a DB2 database?   That also bears mentioning.

Comment: I am pulling data from SAP through installing ODBC driver.

Comment: But where are you executing the query? Sql Server or DB2 ?

Comment: I am executing this query in SQL command of ADO .NET source editor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You appear to be querying a DB2 for IBM i V5 databases, judging by the error message. Indeed there's no `GETDATE()` function in DB2. There's no `DATEADD()` either. Instead, you substitute a value of the [`CURRENT DATE` special register](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_i5_54/db2/rbafzmstspecreg.htm) (variable) and calculate the range like so

```
SELECT * FROM Table 
WHERE CreatedDate BETWEEN CURRENT DATE - 90 DAYS AND CURRENT DATE
```

Comment: Yup, you are right. I got it working by referring this site: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/0211yip/0211yip3.html

Comment: Keep in mind that you are using **IBM DB2** database, no SQL server.

Answer (score 0):

Try this You will get data from last three month to tilldate

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE CreatedDate >= DATEADD(MONTH,-3,getdate())
```

Comment: I have tried this and got the error: ERROR [42S02] [IBM] [System i Access ODBC Driver] [DB2 for i5 / OS] SQL0204 - GETDATE of type * N in * LIBL not found. (CWBODBC.DLL)

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

```
WHERE CreatedDate >= CAST(GETDATE() - 90 AS DATE) 
 AND  CreatedDate <= CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE);
```

OR

```
WHERE CreatedDate >= CAST(DATEADD(MONTH, -3 , GETDATE()) AS DATE) 
 AND  CreatedDate <= CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE);
```

Comment: Got the error as : 
ERROR [42000] [IBM i [System i Access ODBC Driver] [DB2 for i5 / OS] SQL0170 - Number of arguments for function DATE invalid. (CWBODBC.DLL)

Comment: @User5590 If you are getting data from SQL Server 2008, use OLE DB data source instead of using ado.net or ODBC.

Comment: My data is coming from SAP through ODBC and I need to import it to SQL 2008

Comment: None of the above is working. Getting the awkward error as ERROR [42S02] [IBM] [System i Access ODBC Driver] [DB2 for i5 / OS] SQL0204 - GETDATE of type * N in * LIBL not found. (CWBODBC.DLL)

Comment: Keep in mind she/he are using **IBM DB2** database, no SQL server.